# save ids in an array

Tags: php, sql, loops, for-loop, logic

i have a sql table in which there are columns of id, parentid and name

i want to trace parent_id upto ten levels and store them in an array "level[]"
with a for loop

for example : i have an id= 100
this id has parent_id = 80

id no 80 has a parent_id = 72
this id has a parent_id=64
and so on...

in this way i want to save these parent_ids in an array name levels[]

if anyone needs more info plz comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do the trick

```
$level[0] = $parent_id;
        for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++ )
        {
            $j = $i+1;
            $search = "SELECT parent_id FROM `$database`.`$mem` where id='$level[$i]'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $search);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $level[$j] = $row['parent_id'];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you want to save some data which fetched from database in level array

You could use PDO with any fetch style you want [PDO Fetch All](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify the effective SQL you are working with, I will give you the algorithm:

```
getDescendantsOf(id, limit)
    result <- id
    parent <- <select parent id>
    while not (parent is null) and limit > 0
        result <- parent + ',' + result
        parent <- <select parent id>
        limit <- limit - 1
    end while
    return result
end getDescendantsOf
```

This is not SQL code, do not try to execute it. This is an algorithm that can be implemented in SQL.

EDIT:

This is how one can create a stored mysql function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

This is how one can concatenate a varchar to another in MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7642

This is how one can use variables in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

This is how one can use a while cycle in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html

This is how a MySQL stored procedure or function can be called from PHP: http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/42887/0/page/2

So, you need to implement a stored function in MySQL which will contain a while cycle. Each iteration of the while cycle will prepend the parent of the previously found item to a varchar and the stored function will return a varchar, containing the genealogy, separated by comma. You will need to call this from PHP and you will get the IDs. From there on you can use this string for whatever purpose you needed it.

Comment: i didnt understood a single word, i m actually using mysqli, php variables, for loop.. can you show this logrithms by using these format

Comment: @jolly, this is an algorithm, not a logarithm. Logarithm is a function which yields the power you need to raise the base to get the parameter. Here we are talking about an algorithm, which is the way we plan the thought process to occur. You will need to implement this in MySQL to avoid repeatedly sending requests from PHP. I have edited my answer to give you further information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursive function to get all `parent_id`.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname");

function get_all(&$levels, $parent_id = null)
{
    global $link;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE parent_id " . ($parent_id ? 'IS NULL' : "= $parent_id");
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if ($row['parent_id']) {
                $levels[] = $row['parent_id'];
            }
            get_all($levels, $row['id']);
        }
    }
}

$levels = [];
get_all($levels);
```